# Consulta Laravel Eloquient

Tags: laravel, eloquent

se que ésta pregunta es repetitiva, pero luego de leer documentacion y demas, no logro lo siguiente, que es obtener y almacenar en una variabre a traves de Eloquent en Laravel (db=Mysql)
el valor contenido en un campo. Por tinker si lo logro facimelte como deberia, pero en mi codigo no.
Gracias

Mi consulta Eloquent

```
            $gasse = Gasse::select('*')->where('fecha',$fechaParte)->first();
            $estado=$gasse->estado;
```

Mi modelo:

```
  protected $fillable = [
        'area_id',
        'fecha',
        'hora',
        'client_id',
        'pm10',
        'pm316',
        'a9300',
        'pm316_c',
        'a9300_c',
        'estado',



    ];
```

Mi Captura Tiker

[image: Captura Tinke]

Error Codigo

Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
C:\xampp\htdocs\petrolsursa\app\Http\Livewire\ProductionComponent.php:117

ErrorException
Trying to get property 'estado' of non-object
}

```
public function verifyPart($tipoPart,$fechaParte){

    switch($tipoPart) {

        case 'petroleo':

            $production=  Production::select('*')->where( ['fecha' => $fechaParte, 'estado' => 'En Proceso']);

            if ($production='Creado' ||$production='En Proceso'){

                $this->muestraView($tipoPart);

                session()->flash('message','Puede seguir editando el Parte');

            }else{

            }

            break;

        case 'gas':

            //$this->muestraView($tipoPart);

            $gasse = Gasse::select('*')->where('fecha',$fechaParte)->first();

            $estado=$gasse->estado; //linea 117
```

de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrías mirar que error te sale en laravel.log y copiarme el error?, en el log queda más claro.

Comment: Quiere decir que esta condición `where('fecha',$fechaParte)` no se cumple para ningún registro. Revisa cuál es el valor de `$fechaParte` en ese momento

Comment: si cumple, pues tinker me devuelve el resultado,  ahora pago log, gracias nuevamente @oscar-portillo

Comment: log:[2022-01-17 05:40:26] local.ERROR: Trying to get property 'estado' of non-object {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'estado' of non-object at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\petrolsursa\\app\\Http\\Livewire\\ProductionComponent.php:116)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\petrolsursa\\app\\Http\\Livewire\\ProductionComponent.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get p...', 'C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...', 116, Array)

Comment: el valor $fechaparte si corresponde pues luego hice una prueba en ese mismo prodecimiento enviando un mensahe con toostr a la vista y sale fecha coreecta enviada con la variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que el error lo está dando al hacer la consulta ('*'), no es mysql como tal sino algo que asemeja las sentencias SQL.

Estás intentando acceder a la posición de un objeto en un array, también puedes partir de ese error.

Prueba usar lo siguiente [ref](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#select-statements):

usa use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; // para acceder a las tablas por su nombre

Ejemplo de código:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

public function verifyPart($tipoPart,$fechaParte){

    switch($tipoPart) {

        case 'petroleo':

            // $production =  Production::select('*')->where( ['fecha' => $fechaParte, 'estado' => 'En Proceso']);

            $production = DB::table('el_nombre_de_la_tabla')->where( ['fecha' => $fechaParte, 'estado' => 'En Proceso'])->first(); // first() si es solo para uno o get() para varios, pero en el if tendrías que hacer un foreach para recorrer cada uno.

            if ($production->estado = 'Creado' ||$production->estado = 'En Proceso'){

                $this->muestraView($tipoPart);

                session()->flash('message','Puede seguir editando el Parte');

            }else{

            }

            break;

        case 'gas':

            //$this->muestraView($tipoPart);

            $gasse = Gasse::select('*')->where('fecha',$fechaParte)->first();

            $estado=$gasse->estado; //linea 117
```

Comment: gracias, pero sigue el mismo erro, el procedimiento compre es asi

Comment: creo que se lo que pasa el campo estado es de tipo Enum y creo que por ahi va el problema